# undefined function move_upload_file() 

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function move_upload_file() in
>   D:\Compiler\wamp\chuxin\HighApplication\upLoading\file.php on line 14

I don't know how to solve this problem? can you help me?

Comment: move_uploaded_file (move_upload*ed*_file vs move_upload_file)

Answer (score 6):

Wrong function name. Function name must be [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dest_path);
```

Answer (score 4):

The function is called move_uploaded_file
http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 0):

Compare your code with this

**PHP CODE:**

```
    <?php
      if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
      {

        $file = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
        if($file)
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$file);
        }
      }
    ?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="myfile"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

insure that you use in form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
and **file name** is `myfile` also **uploads** is is directory where you store file